# Angular UI datepicker validated as false when empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm using the JqueryUI datepicker(1.0.0) directive with Angular 1.4.9 to display a date of birth. This field is not required and should not be validated unless it's filled.

Once the page loads, the field is validated as true(As expected). And once the user selects a date, it's again valid. But if we were to manually erase the field, the field becomes invalid.

```
<input ui-date="dateOptions" name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dob"/>
```

`ng-model` can be set to the same value before and after, but the value remains invalid.

I've created a JSFiddle that replicates the problem here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nipuna777/ctsmuv80/

Comment: Looks to be an bug in the directive, it doesn't check whether the field is required or not and validates the value - `return _angular2.default.isDate(uiDateConverter.stringToDate(attrs.uiDateFormat, viewValue));`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Is there a way to disable this validation or override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said @nipuna777, it looks like a bug in the datepicker.

We can fix it with a directive.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/owo4dqw6/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.date']);

myApp.directive('uiDateFix', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 100,
    scope: {
      ngRequired: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      var originalValidate = null;
      $timeout(function() {
        if (!originalValidate)
          originalValidate = ngModel.$validators.uiDateValidator;
        ngModel.$validators.uiDateValidator = function uiDateValidator2(modelValue, viewValue) {
          //Define correct validations
          if (viewValue || scope.ngRequired)
            return originalValidate(modelValue, viewValue);
          else
            return true;
        }
      }, 500);
    }
  }
});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.value = 'Superhero';
  $scope.dateOptions = {
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '1900:-0'
  };
  $scope.isReq = true;
  $scope.dob = ""
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-date/1.0.0/date.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1> Datepicker</h1>
    <form name="person">
      <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth: </label>
      <input ui-date="dateOptions" name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dob" ui-date-fix ng-required="isReq" />
       <label for="isReq">Required </label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="isReq" ng-model="isReq" />
      <p>
        dob value: {{dob}}
      </p>
      <p>
        dob valid: {{person.dateOfBirth.$valid}}
      </p>
      <p>
        dob errors: {{person.dateOfBirth.$error}}
      </p>

      <hr>

      <h2>Recreating the problem</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>With the field empty dob is valid</li>
        <li>When you select a value from datepicker again the dob field is valid</li>
        <li>When dob is manually removed, the field becomes invalid</li>
      </ol>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you need a workaround if it is already fixed in the plugin

Comment: I added my answer, after answering a fixed version of the directive `ui-date`. Of course, it is better to use a fixed version of the directive `ui-date`.

Answer (score 1):

It is [an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/issues/152) in the validator of the plugin, it [is fixed](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/commit/93e6141fd45e2ffd28124bc66b8452c8374c25ff) in the [master branch/dist/date.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/ui-date/master/dist/date.js).

So you can use that file instead of the one in the cdn to fix it